# Clearing CGPath path after drawing is done

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgpath

I've written a program for drawing in iOS in touchesMoved() method.

```
CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), path);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextDrawPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGPathStroke);
```

How can i clear the path drawn and restore the original view?

Comment: you mean that you want to remove the drawing?

Comment: yeah, i want to clear the drawing and restore the original view

Comment: sorry but i left my workplace and i didn't check the reply

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put an invisible view above your view of drawing and add the path traced by the user only when u are sure that the user will not undo. If the user wants the undo action, don't add the path to the context. Thats my logic. I am not sure how it can be implemted.
Hope this helps.